# How to start an activity that is already loaded into memory

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I have an application that I have ported from Windows to Andriod and iOS. In this application, screens (activities) should be loaded via Reflection using a predefined xml and some business logic needs to be done on the screen (activity) before it is started. so the question is how do I start an Activity that I have already loaded. Sample code like this:

```
MyActivity activity = Activity.LoadActivityFromReflection(/* some parameters passed*/);
DoSomeWork_PrepareAndBindActivityToItsController(activity);
// now how can I start this activity. I know I could do the following 
Intent intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeOf(MyActivity));
startActivity(intent);
```

but I am afraid that this would re-instantiate the activity and all the work that was done to prepare and bind the it will go away.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the answer from Xamarin, I am posting it here to help anybody who is trying to do the same thing. Also, I found a way to go around this, and I will post my solution here once it is done.

Dear Has,

Loading `Activities` by reflection sounds like an interesting approach. Since I haven't tried it myself, I'm not 100% sure this will answer your question, but here are my first thoughts:

It looks like you are constructing a special *instance* of an `Activity` that you want to display. To make this work, you would need a way to push the instance onto the "`task stack`" (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html), but it is not possible to directly manipulate existing task stacks (mentioned on slide #105 of http://www.slideshare.net/RanNachmany/manipulating-android-tasks-and-back-stack). Actually, even generating a brand new task stack using a `TaskStackBuilder` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) requires using `Intents`.

> In short, Intents are the only way to start Activities in Android.

I think the most direct solution in your case would be to create the whole `MyActivity` *class* by reflection. Then you could use an Intent and start the Activity in the normal way. "`DoSomeWork_PrepareAndBindActivityToItsController(activity)`" would probably be part of the the "`onStart()`" callback.

Best,
Brendan @ Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am aware of being able to store data and reaccess it with any kind of consistency is to place it in an Application class. As I understand the Android life cycle as a whole I don't know if I would recommend going that route. I find it's very hard to ensure that an Activity was started with the correct parameters if you try to define it explicitly.

For example, if you simply turn your device the activity OnCreate is called (plus onresume etc). So that being said if your trying to control the layout programmically, or doing some time consuming initial work to define the layout, you may want to just store the values in the bundle when its destroyed, and when you reload try to use saved values as you had before.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, but I do not have issue with sharing data across Activities, that is done. What I want is to load and DISPLAY the activity myself as I need to call few methods on the activity object